# Rest API Architecture - GET a resource by alias

Tags: node.js, rest, architecture, api-design

I need a help from you about REST Arch.
I've a resource and I can retrieve it with the classical GET /resource/ID URI, but this resource has an alias and someone want to GET this resource by calling it via alias.

There is a good way to do so by calling a GET /resource/?alias=x, take the ID and then go to the details /resource/ID.

Do you have any good idea about other ways to do this?

Comment: Just note, plural form should be used /resources/ since it is collection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to stay within the constraints of the REST architecture, you definitely need to stay with the verb GET.  You can't add other methods.

Now you need to decide how the resource is named.  You have a canonical name (your id), and an alias.  One approach is to set up the controller for

```
GET /things/:id
```

so that `:id` can be *either* the canonical id *or* the alias.  So you'd have

```
app.get('/resources/id', function (req, res) {
  var id = req.params.id;
  if (isAlias(id)) id = resolveAlias(id);
  Thing.findById(id, null, function (err, thing) {
    if (err) res.json(400, err)
    if (thing === null) res.json(404, {"No such id": id})
    res.json(thing)
  });
});
```

You can also put in the alias as a query parameter, like you suggested.

I suspect the only other way might be to use a different url (somethng other than `things`) but I think this is disingenuous because you want to return the same representation whether or not you use the id or the alias.  It should be the same controller, and you should be using GET, so I believe you need to go with the path parameter or query parameter.

This choice is independent of query rewriting, by the way.

Comment: Will using /things/alias/x in addition to /things/id considered non-REST?

Comment: If you want to be pedantic, `/things/alias/x` is saying that `alias` is _sub-resource_ of `things`.  I have seen path parameters used as "attributes" before but it feels wrong to me and I avoid doing so.  But "being 100%" restful is not necessarily the law, so feel free to add that as an answer of your own. The OP might like it, even if it is "less pure". :)

Comment: I like this answer because it makes it transparent to the consumer.

Comment: Thanks Ray, Hector and rdodev.
@Ray, I agree with your answer but calling one URI with two different IDs without specify the difference it's not so transparent for the client, I think.
What about GET /things/:id?q=alias  or something like that. Maybe it could be specified the ID into some header? (but what?) :-)

Comment: Does it really matter whether one is the alias and one is the real id to the client?

Answer (score 4):

There is nothing wrong with a resource having two URIs (or two URIs pointing to the same resource, to put it another way). For example

```
GET www.myweatherapi.com/2013/11/18/rainfall

GET www.myweatherapi.com/today/rainfall
```

can both point to the same resource. You could say the latter is an alias of the former, or vice versa, it doesn't really matter, they both identify the same resource. You don't need to start explicitly labeling something as an alias of something else.

If the alias is temporary and may be gone in the future you could use the 307 response, temporary redirect. This tells the client that they should go to a different URI to find the resource, but not to assume that will be true in the future (eg limit how long you cache this).

*As an aside, the client should not construct URIs, the server should return a content type format (HTML, JSON etc) that contains a way to identify the resources the client wants along with the URI of where to find them. For example a link in HTML saying "Todays Rainfall" with the URI to that resource. The user follows that link if they want todays rainfall*

Comment: Thanks Cormac Mulhall,
I'd like to avoid to call the same resource with two different URIs in my case because the "identity" of the resource is very - strong - for me. Anyway thanks for your sample of URIs.
franco

Comment: I agree completely with your conclusion but your example has a small problem. A `today` resource isn't idempotent. A better example might be `2013/321` (day of year) or `1384732800` (unix time) as aliases for `2013/11/18`.

Comment: I'm not really following. Why would you not be able to do an idempotent request to `today` resource?

Comment: I generally like this example and I think it makes sense to use it in the context of getting today's rainfall. But I think nicerobot's point about idempotency is valid for data-modifying requests: if I hit `today/rainfall` twice with the same request, the second call will have a different effect if it falls on the other side of the date boundary. There is also a related point about _deterministic behavior_ (though this is NOT a REST requirement AFAIK): the endpoint will behave differently depending on the time of the request.

Comment: Not exactly. Say you have a resource `/today/color` and you `PUT red` at 11.59pm and then `PUT red` at 1.34am both requests are idempotent. You can do that twice or you can do that 1,000 times, in all situtations the `/today/color` resource will be `red` at the end. I think what you both mean is that you might be trying to access the resource `/aug/20/color` in one request and then `/aug/21/color` in the next when you don't mean to. Which yes if you don't actually want `/today/color` don't make state change via that resource, be specific to a day instead